# How do I write an assert for selenium to ensure a newly added item was in fact added?

Tags: c#, selenium, automated-tests

I have a form that is used to add a new user.  My assert is failing because it cannot find the item.  When I run my program manually I can see that the user was in fact added.  This worked once, but the next time I went to run the program it couldn't find the user:

```
var email = wait.Until((d) => d.PageSource.Contains("email@example.com"));
Assert.True(email);
```

I think it might be failing now because I have added more users to the page so now when it tries to find the newly added one it is at the bottom of the page.  I searched how to scroll with selenium and found this, but it did not work for me:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor) driver;
js.ExecuteScript("javascript:window.scrollBy(250,350)");
```

As requested here is my html.  The newly added user gets added to the bottom of the table.

```html
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Richard Swave</td>
        <td>email@example.com</td>
        <td>Developer</td>
        <td>
            <div class="pointer">
                <div class="sprk-o-Stack sprk-o-Stack--split@xs" data-id="">
                    <div class="sprk-o-Stack__item sprk-o-Stack__item--half@xs sprk-o-Box" data-id="">
                        <div class="updateUser">
                            <svg class="sprk-c-Icon sprk-c-Icon--l" viewBox="0 0 64 64" data-id="">
                                <use xlink:href="#editable"></use>
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <div class="sprk-o-Stack__item sprk-o-Stack__item--half@xs sprk-o-Box" data-id="">
                    <svg class="sprk-c-Icon sprk-c-Icon--l" viewBox="0 0 64 64" data-id="">
                        <use xlink:href="#trash"></use>
                    </svg>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Frances Ferdinand</td>
        <td>email@example.com</td>
        <td>Developer</td>
        <td>
            <div class="pointer">
                <div class="sprk-o-Stack sprk-o-Stack--split@xs" data-id="">
                    <div class="sprk-o-Stack__item sprk-o-Stack__item--half@xs sprk-o-Box" data-id="">
                        <div class="updateUser">
                            <svg class="sprk-c-Icon sprk-c-Icon--l" viewBox="0 0 64 64" data-id="">
                                <use xlink:href="#editable"></use>
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <div class="sprk-o-Stack__item sprk-o-Stack__item--half@xs sprk-o-Box" data-id="">
                    <svg class="sprk-c-Icon sprk-c-Icon--l" viewBox="0 0 64 64" data-id="">
                        <use xlink:href="#trash"></use>
                    </svg>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Vincent Vango</td>
    <td>email@example.com</td>
    <td>Developer</td>
    <td>
        <div class="pointer">
            <div class="sprk-o-Stack sprk-o-Stack--split@xs" data-id="">
                <div class="sprk-o-Stack__item sprk-o-Stack__item--half@xs sprk-o-Box" data-id="">
                    <div class="updateUser">
                        <svg class="sprk-c-Icon sprk-c-Icon--l" viewBox="0 0 64 64" data-id="">
                            <use xlink:href="#editable"></use>
                        </svg>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <div class="sprk-o-Stack__item sprk-o-Stack__item--half@xs sprk-o-Box" data-id="">
                <svg class="sprk-c-Icon sprk-c-Icon--l" viewBox="0 0 64 64" data-id="">
                    <use xlink:href="#trash"></use>
                </svg>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Matthew McConaughey</td>
        <td>email@example.com</td>
        <td>Developer</td>
        <td>
            <div class="pointer">
                <div class="sprk-o-Stack sprk-o-Stack--split@xs" data-id="">
                    <div class="sprk-o-Stack__item sprk-o-Stack__item--half@xs sprk-o-Box" data-id="">
                        <div class="updateUser">
                            <svg class="sprk-c-Icon sprk-c-Icon--l" viewBox="0 0 64 64" data-id="">
                                <use xlink:href="#editable"></use>
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <div class="sprk-o-Stack__item sprk-o-Stack__item--half@xs sprk-o-Box" data-id="">
                    <svg class="sprk-c-Icon sprk-c-Icon--l" viewBox="0 0 64 64" data-id="">
                        <use xlink:href="#trash"></use>
                    </svg>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Debbie Downer</td>
        <td>email@example.com</td>
        <td>Developer</td>
        <td>
            <div class="pointer">
                <div class="sprk-o-Stack sprk-o-Stack--split@xs" data-id="">
                    <div class="sprk-o-Stack__item sprk-o-Stack__item--half@xs sprk-o-Box" data-id="">
                        <div class="updateUser"><svg class="sprk-c-Icon sprk-c-Icon--l" viewBox="0 0 64 64" data-id="">
                            <use xlink:href="#editable"></use>
                        </svg>
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                <div class="sprk-o-Stack__item sprk-o-Stack__item--half@xs sprk-o-Box" data-id="">
                    <svg class="sprk-c-Icon sprk-c-Icon--l" viewBox="0 0 64 64" data-id="">
                        <use xlink:href="#trash"></use>
                    </svg>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Moody Judy</td>
        <td>email@example.com</td>
        <td>Developer</td>
        <td>
            <div class="pointer">
                <div class="sprk-o-Stack sprk-o-Stack--split@xs" data-id="">
                    <div class="sprk-o-Stack__item sprk-o-Stack__item--half@xs sprk-o-Box" data-id="">
                        <div class="updateUser">
                            <svg class="sprk-c-Icon sprk-c-Icon--l" viewBox="0 0 64 64" data-id="">
                                <use xlink:href="#editable"></use>
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <div class="sprk-o-Stack__item sprk-o-Stack__item--half@xs sprk-o-Box" data-id="">
                    <svg class="sprk-c-Icon sprk-c-Icon--l" viewBox="0 0 64 64" data-id="">
                        <use xlink:href="#trash"></use>
                    </svg>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Bobby Brown</td>
        <td>email@example.com</td>
        <td>Developer</td>
        <td>
            <div class="pointer">
                <div class="sprk-o-Stack sprk-o-Stack--split@xs" data-id="">
                    <div class="sprk-o-Stack__item sprk-o-Stack__item--half@xs sprk-o-Box" data-id="">
                        <div class="updateUser">
                            <svg class="sprk-c-Icon sprk-c-Icon--l" viewBox="0 0 64 64" data-id="">
                                <use xlink:href="#editable"></use>
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sprk-o-Stack__item sprk-o-Stack__item--half@xs sprk-o-Box" data-id="">
                        <svg class="sprk-c-Icon sprk-c-Icon--l" viewBox="0 0 64 64" data-id="">
                            <use xlink:href="#trash"></use>
                        </svg>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: probably don't need a scroll.  I'd avoid using "PageSource".  If the DOM is updated via javascript this may not reflect the current DOM.  Instead use Selenium/Webdriver find method to find the element.  (I usually do a FindElements and check returned size.)  I also avoid using Lambdas with Selenium.  It's unnecessary and makes the code less readable. (Though I guess that's a personal taste thing...)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a representative amount of HTML on the page, especially the part where you expect the e-mail to be showing up.

Comment: @GregBurghardt I added the html.

Comment: It is still a little difficult to create the proper locator for you in Selenium. Can you add the `<table>` tag as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead, wait for an element to be present containing the e-mail address you are making an assertion for.

If the HTML does not contain any whitespace or formatting characters, try an exact text match:

```
wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.XPath("//td[text() = 'email@example.com']"));
```

Otherwise, try a `contains(...)` match:

```
wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.XPath("//td[contains(., 'email@example.com')]"));
```